# Using Fabric 2 and Fabric 3 in the same project

Tags: python, python-3.x, fabric

I am currently using Fabric3 in a python project and I want to use the azure-cli package. However when I install the package, it appears to break my Fabric3 install:

> root ~ $ fab --version
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/bin/fab", line 7, in
>
> from Fabric3.main import program
>
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Fabric3'

I noticed that the pip install of azure-cli appears to install fabric (2.5.0), and this appears to overwrite some of the fabric files within the "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usrbin/fab" script and the "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/fabric/" directory.

So my question is, is there a way to run different versions of Fabric within the same project?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you use fabric3? Does it have a specific feature fabric2 doesn't have? Remember that fabric3 is an UNOFFICIAL fork op fabric2! If I were you, I would use only fabric 2

Comment: I believe Fabric3 was used before Fabric2 was released. It's a dependency used widely in the project, so it's not really an option to migrate to Fabric2

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do this by using python virtual environments.

I created a virtual env, activated the virtual env, installed the pip package, deactivated the virtual env, then used Fabric 3 to call the function in the venv.

```
python -m venv azure_cli_venv
. azure_cli_venv/bin/activate
pip install azure-cli
deactivate
```

Fabric3 local call:

```
local(f'./azure_cli_venv/bin/az --help
```